# Lodash map values in a nested array

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have this sort of data, which we usually grab from api, and it is my first time using lodash.

```
{
  "_id": "93866",
  "stats": [
    {
      "points": 86,
      "pos": 11,
      "createdAt": "2019-01-16T10:13:40.650Z",
      "updatedAt": "2019-01-16T10:13:40.825Z"
    },
    {
      "points": 79,
      "pos": 26,
      "createdAt": "2019-01-16T10:13:40.650Z",
      "updatedAt": "2019-01-16T10:13:40.825Z"
    },
    {
      "points": 64,
      "pos": 39,
      "createdAt": "2019-01-16T10:13:40.650Z",
      "updatedAt": "2019-01-16T10:13:40.825Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

All I want is to achieve like this

```
[ [ 86, 11 ], [ 79, 26 ], [ 64, 39 ] ]
```

I can simply do this in a native way by doing this,

```
var result = data.stats.map(o => [o.points, o.pos])
// => [ [ 86, 11 ], [ 79, 26 ], [ 64, 39 ] ]
```

which yields the expected result but the environment I'm working depends on the use of lodash.

I have tried so far `_.map(data.stats, 'points')` but Im not sure how I make it to achieve like this `[ [ 86, 11 ], [ 79, 26 ], [ 64, 39 ] ]`

So how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `object#destructring` in the function callback.

```js
let data = {"_id":"93866","stats":[{"points":86,"pos":11,"createdAt":"2019-01-16T10:13:40.650Z","updatedAt":"2019-01-16T10:13:40.825Z"},{"points":79,"pos":26,"createdAt":"2019-01-16T10:13:40.650Z","updatedAt":"2019-01-16T10:13:40.825Z"},{"points":64,"pos":39,"createdAt":"2019-01-16T10:13:40.650Z","updatedAt":"2019-01-16T10:13:40.825Z"}]},
    result = _.map(data.stats, ({points, pos}) => [points,pos]);
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

You can use lodash's [`_.at()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#at) with [`_.map()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#map):

```js
const data = {"_id":"93866","stats":[{"points":86,"pos":11,"createdAt":"2019-01-16T10:13:40.650Z","updatedAt":"2019-01-16T10:13:40.825Z"},{"points":79,"pos":26,"createdAt":"2019-01-16T10:13:40.650Z","updatedAt":"2019-01-16T10:13:40.825Z"},{"points":64,"pos":39,"createdAt":"2019-01-16T10:13:40.650Z","updatedAt":"2019-01-16T10:13:40.825Z"}]};

const result = _.map(data.stats, o => _.at(o, ['points', 'pos']));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

You can also use the [lodash/fp](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide) versions of `_.map()` and `_.at()` to create function:

```js
const data = {"_id":"93866","stats":[{"points":86,"pos":11,"createdAt":"2019-01-16T10:13:40.650Z","updatedAt":"2019-01-16T10:13:40.825Z"},{"points":79,"pos":26,"createdAt":"2019-01-16T10:13:40.650Z","updatedAt":"2019-01-16T10:13:40.825Z"},{"points":64,"pos":39,"createdAt":"2019-01-16T10:13:40.650Z","updatedAt":"2019-01-16T10:13:40.825Z"}]};

const fn = _.map(_.at(['points', 'pos']));

const result = fn(data.stats);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've pretty much figured it out, you just have to combine your *native* version with your `lodash` attempt:

```
var result = _.map(data.stats, o => [o.points, o.pos]);
```

As you can see, I replaced the second parameter to `_.map` (which was `'points'`) with the function used in your *native* version.

Answer (score 1):

Here is:

```
_.map(data.stats, obj => [ obj.points, obj.pos ])
```

Edit: @Hassan Imam made an interesting answer using destructuring object